# simple exponential smoothing with drift

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing

I have researched all over the text books and software (R/SAS/SPSS), but I have not encountered Simple Exponential Smoothing (SES) with a **drift** ?

Is it possible to add a **drift** term to Simple exponential smoothing, so that SES captures the direction of the trend? If yes, how is this implemented in software like `forecast` package in `R` or any other software?

Also, is SES with drift equivalent to ARIMA(0,1,1) + Drift ?

Comment: You haven't looked very hard: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=simple%20exponential%20smoothing%20with%20drift

Comment: You could also try reading the documentation to the forecast package: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/thetaf

Answer (score 1):

If the drift changes over time, then you can use double exponential smoothing known as the Holt-Winters procedure.

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing

R has an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. The theta method of Assimakopoulos and Nikolopoulos (2000) is equivalent to simple exponential smoothing with drift. This is demonstrated in Hyndman and Billah (2003). This is already implemented in the `forecast` package in `R`.
2. Yes. SES is equivalent to ARIMA(0,1,1), so adding constant with make them equivalent too.

References

1. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.1/topics/thetaf
2. https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm#ses

Comment: Actually #1 is partially wrong. It is equivalent to SES with drift only in certain circumstances (no seasonality is detected). See: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207016300243